# Using VB 6.0 Form in .net which is embeded in a DLL

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, vb6

I have a DLL of a VB 6 Project that has one class and a form. The form is called from that class when its constructor is called. I made a DLL from the project, add that DLL is in my .NET project references. Now when I call that class DLL it gives the following error:

```
Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {4E44E1A1-391D-4846-B733-2618249FE35A} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800a0196.
```

Which means the form is not opening.

Comment: I assume this is a VB6 COM DLL, not an ActiveX control with a .DLL extension?  Is this happening in your Visual Studio dotNet environment, or only when you deploy your app?

Comment: Sometimes regsvr32 helps

Answer (score 0):

Forms in a VB6 ActiveX DLL must be opened modally from .NET. Is you form modal?

Comment: They don't have to be modal. The COM DLL can have forms open for their entire life time if required.

Comment: Refined my answer to only address VB6 ActiveX interactions. I just tested this again and from .NET, error "Non-modal forms cannot be displayed in this host application from an ActiveX DLL, ActiveX Control, or Property Page." is thrown.